# Using fetch in nodejs returns Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, fetch, unexpected-token

My file fetch.js:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
url = "https://www.google.com"

const getTours = async (url) => {
    try {
        const resp = await fetch(url)
        console.log("fetch", resp)
        return resp
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

getTours(url)
```

I did in terminal:

```
npm init
npm install node-fetch
node fetch.js
```

I got as a result:

```
/home/yan/Desktop/Node Tutorial/fetch.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import fetch from 'node-fetch'
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

I tried to replace the import with a require as such:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
url = "https://www.google.com"

const getTours = async (url) => {
    try {
        const resp = await fetch(url)
        console.log("fetch", resp)
        return resp
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

getTours(url)
```

but I got a similar error:

```
/home/yan/Desktop/Node Tutorial/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9
import http from 'node:http';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yan/Desktop/Node Tutorial/fetch.js:1:77)
```

Can you tell me what is going on ? I'm following some tutorials who have the same code and are running with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

The similar error is related to the first, but for a different package: `node-http`

Try this:

`const NodeHttp = require('node-http');`

Comment: Hi, I did as you told but I still have the same error: Unexpected token import for ```import http from 'node:http';```
I guess this line is called by the line ```const fetch = require("node-fetch")```

Comment: The error is not coming from the fetch.js file but an index.js file. Do you have any file like that? @YannickPezeu

Comment: Yes I have a file like that but I guess it has been created in the node module when I ran ```npm install node-fetch```

It looks like my computer does not recognize the "import" keyWord

Answer (score 0):

In your "package.json" add "type":"module" and also declare url using const.

```
{
  "main": "fetch.js",
  "type": "module",
}

import fetch from "node-fetch";
const url = "https://www.google.com"

const getTours = async (url) => {
 try {
     const resp = await fetch(url)
     console.log("fetch", resp)
     return resp
  } 
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
 }

 getTours(url)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nghf.png)

Comment: Hi, I did as you told but it does not help.

Here is my package.json: ```{
  "name": "node-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "fetch.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Hi, the url variable was also undeclared. have you fixed it?

Comment: Ray3du: Yes I did add the const as suggested: ```const url = "https://www.google.com"```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `esm`  module which allows to use either `import` or `require`.

First, install `esm` in your project running this:

`$ npm install --save esm`

Then, update your node start script to use `esm` with the following line:

`node -r esm app.js`

Comment: Hi, I did as you told and I get this error:
```yan@yan-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Node Tutorial$ node -r esm fetch.js
/home/yan/Desktop/Node Tutorial/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:1
Error [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol 'node:' not supported. Expected 'file:'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yan/Desktop/Node Tutorial/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by upgrading my node version with nvm.

I have a node version of v8.17.0
I upgraded it to the LTS (long term support) of my current time which was v16.13.0 by running the code:

`nvm install 16.13.0`

To find your current LTS please follow this page: https://nodejs.org/en/